# Flutter: skips assign variable

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a class which will return a list of some widgets, but when I debug the code it skips `currentWidget = myList;`.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
class _FileLoader {
  _FileLoader() {
    currentWidgets = new List < Widget > ();
  }
  List < Widget > currentWidgets;
  List < Widget > getWidgets(String token) {
    _futureLoadWidgets(token);
    return currentWidgets;
  }
  Future < void > _futureLoadWidgets(String token) async {
    List < Widget > myList = new List < Widget > ();
    var response = await http.get(token);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      for (var o in jsonDecode(response.body)) {
        myList.add(new Text(o['user']['name']));
        myList.add(new Text(o['urls']['small']));
      }
      currentWidgets = myList;
    }
  }
}
```

P.S: beginner at dart/flutter. Would be very helpful if you also give some documentation to read when I stuck next time. Thanks.

Comment: How exactly did you debug it? As @Doneke says it is possible that the response code was different than 200. And, because _futureLoadWidgets() method is an async method it is possible that it hasn't completed before you tried to use the currentWidgets field.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to print the statusCode before the `if(response...)` to check its value ?

Maybe the statusCode is different from 200 and that's why your list is not filled, because it doesn't go inside your `if()`.

Hope it helps !